# Make checkbox checked for specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 check box with following values ,
**7:00
8:00
8:30
9:00**
9:30
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00

now just consider 7:00 to 9:00 has been checked already. When i check 11:30 i should get all values should be get selected between 9:00 to 11:30

so after check 11:00 my result should be

**7:00
8:00
8:30
9:00
9:30
10:00
10:30
11:00**
11:30
12:00

My code so far :

HTML Code is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="8:00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="8:30" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="9:00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="9:30" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="10:00" />    
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="10:30" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="11:00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="11:30" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="12:00" />
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="12:30" />
```

Jquery Code is

```
var chkdtime = $('input[name="timecheckbox"]:checked').map(
    function() 
    {
        return this.value;
    }
).get(); 

var a=chkdtime.shift();
var b=chkdtime.pop();
```

Comment: Can you post HTML code?

Comment: Is it posible to have data attribute in your HTML ?

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic here, but `.filter` seems to be the way to go for this.

Comment: @Merianos Nikos : Yes i can have data attribute

Comment: But what should happen if you have **7:00 8:00 8:30 9:00** 9:30 and then you uncheck 8:30? Should it become **7:00 8:00** 8:30 9:00 9:30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will do what you want:

```js
var $checks = $(':checkbox[name=timer]').on('change', function() {
    
    var $checked = $checks.filter(':checked'),
        changedIndex = $checks.index(this),
        $start = $checked.eq(0),
        $end = $checked.eq($checked.length - 1),
        from = $checks.index($start),
        to = $checks.index($end);
    
    if (changedIndex < to) {
        $checks.slice(changedIndex).prop('checked', false);
        to = changedIndex;
    }
    
    $checks.slice(from, to).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="8:00" checked /> 8:00 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="8:30" checked /> 8:30 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="9:00" checked /> 9:00 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="9:30" checked /> 9:30 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="10:00" /> 10:00 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="10:30" /> 10:30 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="11:00" /> 11:00 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="11:30" /> 11:30 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="12:00" /> 12:00 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="timer" id="timer" value="12:30" /> 12:30 <br>
```

Te key idea is to calculate indexes of the checked checkboxes using `index()` method and then check/uncheck values in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".autocheck").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      value = this.value;
      $('.autocheck').each(function(){
        if (this.value == value){
          return false;
        } 
        this.checked = true;
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="8:00" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="8:30" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="9:00" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="9:30" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="10:00" />    
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="10:30" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="11:00" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="11:30" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="12:00" />
<input type="checkbox" class="autocheck"   value="12:30" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW I don't think using the same name for every check box is a good idea if you want to access values from server side after submitting the form.